# rails_admin_globalize_field support to file upload for globalized translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-admin, globalize

I am using globalize gem for some locales.
I have added a field in translation that saves different image for different locales.
Rails admin globalize field only supports for string and it doesn't provide any option to upload a file.
How can I achieve this option?

Answer (score 2):

For uploads you must use some processing method to allow storing your file under a simple string field.
Usually you would use some [solution for file uploads, like Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/) and in this specific case you would also have to [use Globalize to manage Carrierwave translated fields](https://github.com/dalpo/carrierwave_globalize), after you setup both gems in you `gemfile` and ran `bundle install` you would have to setup uploaders for each file upload rule you would like to enforce i.e.:

```
rails generate uploader Avatar
```

Then, initialize the uploader on your model file `app/models/assets.rb` on the string column/field like the code below:

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
  extend CarrierwaveGlobalize
  # Globalize translated attributes
  translates :avatar
  mount_translated_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 end
```